# Worklight fails to install customization jar

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have three projects in my workspace, two deploy to the server correctly, the third has just begun to give this error:

```
Failed to install and start project customization from file <path>MyProj-customization.jar
```

I've seen this before on other projects and usually it's sufficient to start the server for another project and come back to the one with problems. When that doesn't work the next recipe (found on developer works) is

```
Exit Eclipse/Worklight Studio

Delete <workspace>/WorkLightServerHome
delete project bin

Start Studio, rebuild
```

That also doesn't work. Finally there's a further recipe on developer works

```
When Eclipse is not running, go to:
     1. <path-to-your-Eclipse-folder>\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi
     2. Delete the .bundle* files
     3. Start Eclipse
     4. Build and deploy
```

Again this does not clear the problem, assuming I've understood step 2 correctly, I found exactly one file whose name is of the form .bundle* and a bundles directory with several sub-directories. I deleted only the .bundlexxx file.

Any other suggestions?

I would have expected that creating a new workspace would fix it, but on this occasion no such luck.

---

No true solution on this occasion. Normally a new workspace as a method of last resot has always worked in the past. In this case I found no alternative to reinstallation of Worklight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the attempts you have tried, also try creating a new workspace and import the 'offending' project to it.
If all fails, have a new instance of Eclipse (Java EE, 4.2.2 SR2), re-install Worklight Studio and import the project.

Comment: Did that, and still no joy.

Comment: what about deleting the .war file from the bin folder? how is this project different from the other, working, two projects?

Comment: That was amongst the recipes I tried, listed in the original post. In principle there is no difference in this project, I've been working with it for some time and the others. I'm sharing the project with two other team members, they have no problem.

Comment: Export your version of the project and give it to your team member, have him/her import it to a new workspace. See if it fails as well. Also, what is the Worklight version used?

Comment: If you create a new project does it happen still? And, a bit far-fetched, have you tried a new Eclipse installation?

Comment: we're sharing the project via RTC, I'm not sure what an export would tell us over our sharing by that method. I'm betting that a complete new Eclipse/worklight install will be fine ...

Comment: For the record a complete install of Worklight, new workspace, fetch project from RTC - all works correctly.

Comment: Weird. :/ I've added it to my answer for future reference. You're welcomed to mark it as Answered.