# Deployment fails with 'An internal error occurred during: "Start Worklight Server"'

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno, ibm-mobilefirst

I have `Worklight Developer 5.0.6` installed on `Eclipse 4.2.2` (Juno).

Trying to deploy a `plain-vanilla Worklight` project (`hybrid WL` application created w/ Wizard), I get a pop-up window entitled *Problem Occurred*. The *Details* view shows this error message:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Start Worklight Server". 
org/apache/tools/ant/types/selectors/FileSelector
```

The Worklight Console in Eclipse shows this:

```
[2013-05-28 09:51:58]             Worklight Server started successfully on localhost:8080   
[2013-05-28 09:51:58]             Activating Worklight project: DemoAppProject...   
[2013-05-28 09:51:58]             Customization not found for project DemoAppProject. 
Building explicitly.
```

Checking the `Worklight` Console on `http://localhost:8080/console` I see that the server is running, but there's no active project.

What am I missing?

Comment: Check the port no 8080 is available to use. As worklight by default takes it.

Comment: As mentionned in my original post, I do see the WL Console in the browser under the well-known URL, i.e., port 8080 is actually listened to by the WL server. BUT, the project is not deployed in the server due to the errors reported. So, why do I get these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bluez,

Based on your comments to my questions below,
I've installed Eclipse Classic 4.2.2 (Juno, on my Mac OS X 10.8.3) and Worklight Studio plug-in from the [IBM website](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/download/) you've linked to.
Created a new Worklight project and application. Build all and Deploy - deployment passed successfully.

Make sure that:

- The "check for updates" checkbox is ticked before starting the plug-in installation.
- You have Java JDK version 6 or later installed

---

1. Is this Eclipse **Java EE** 4.2.2 (Juno SR2), or another variant?
2. Does the project's .war file exist under the project's bin\ folder?
3. Is this a clean installation of Eclipse and Worklight plug-in, or an upgrade?

   - Try suggestions (from both the questions and anwers) from this question: [Worklight fails to install customization jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693774/worklight-fails-to-install-customization-jar)

Comment: ad 1) No, it's not, it is a Eclipse Classic to which I added the Android Developer tools first and then the Worklight Developer edition , which I obtained from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/download/ and *not* from http://http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-worklight-developer-edition .

Comment: ad 2) The bin\ folder is empty.   
ad 3) Yes, it was a clean install.

Comment: Original problem solved. I installed Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Version: Juno SR 2, Build id: 20130225-0426 and IBM Worklight Developer Edition V5.0.6.1 from the Eclipse marketplace. Now, the creation, build, deployment and previewing of a WL default application works.  Unfortunately, the deployment to my Android phone using ADT 22.0.1 fails with a `ClassNofFoundException: Didn't find class "com.WLDefault.WLDefault" on path: /data/app/com.WLDefault-1.apk`.

Comment: The solution to the `ClassNotFoundException` is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783991/ibm-worklight-android-sdk-emulator-deployment-issue-unfortunately-app-h). All fine now.